# Jquery removeClass nothing work

Tags: jquery, removeclass

Sample code and example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QFWLk/).

```
$("#menus > li > ul > li > a").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
```

but click and selected background is work an other click multi selection is not remove not work... Please help and solutions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the click handlers registered to `a` elements, but it has no siblings. You need to go to the parent `li` element find its siblings then drill down to the `a` elements inside those sibling elements

You need

```
$("#menus > li > ul > li > a").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("selected").parent().siblings().find('a').removeClass("selected");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/p9axP/)

It again has a bug, if you navigate between two types, so try

```
$("#menus > li > ul > li > a").click(function(){
    $('#menus a.selected').removeClass("selected");
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/p9axP/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Your `a` element has no siblings. You have to select `a` elements in the parent `li`'s siblings.

```
$("#menus > li > ul > li > a").click(function(){
    $('a',$(this).toggleClass("selected").parent().siblings()).removeClass("selected");
}
```

See it working:
http://jsfiddle.net/QFWLk/1/

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 $("#menus > li > ul > li > a").click(function(){
        $("#menus > li > ul > li > a").removeClass('selected');
        $(this).toggleClass("selected");

});
```

Hope it will help